# The principle behind Youglish for searching YouTube videos

Tags: search, subtitle

I made efforts to create a functionality similar to Youglish
But the YouTube Data API does not support subtitle search
How can one search YouTube subtitles and find the corresponding scenes?
Even if it's not specific, I would appreciate some guidance or direction. Thank you